# How do I use message() in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a CMakeLists with this code:

```
macro(set_up_additional_targets)
    add_custom_target(generate_things
        message("Generating stuff")
        COMMAND python3 generator.py --outfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sources/stuff
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/generator/
    )
endmacro(set_up_additional_targets)
```

I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `Generating\ stuff'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cd /home/me/workspaces/foo/tools/generator && message ( Generating\ stuff )'
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/generate_things.dir/build.make:70: CMakeFiles/generate_things] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:699: CMakeFiles/generate_things.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:706: CMakeFiles/generate_things.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:439: generate_things] Error 2
```

I changed from `COMMAND echo "Generating stuff"` to `message("Generating stuff")` to become more platform independent, but it obviously doesn't work. It is not clear from the CMake manual how this could be wrong, though, as usual with CMake, there are no examples in the manual.

What is my mistake?

Comment: You can use [`cmake -E echo <message>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) to be more platform independent (use `${CMAKE_COMMAND}` instead of `cmake`, if you're running this via `execute_process`, `add_custom_target` or similar command from your cmake project). Alternatively a cmake script file could be used with `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P myscript.cmake`; this file could contain `message()` and `execute_process()`. The `COMMENT` option suggested by Kamath is preferable in this specific use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COMMENT` should serve your purpose here, [see](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html).

`MESSAGE` is evaluated at CMake parsing step, [see](https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/cmake-stages.html).